# Numerically approximating an integral question of understanding

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, definite-integrals

[image]

I do not understand, can we just choose any number between $a$ and $b$, because my intuition says that if we would freely choose a number between the upper bound and the lower bound of the integral, that the error would change.

Can somebody please explain what this error actually means?

Comment: Not sure what you are asking. The text in your picture clearly says "there exists a number $\xi$". Why would you think you can choose it arbitrarily?

Comment: In https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trapezoidal_rule#Proof you can read "Now suppose that $\vert f^{\prime\prime}(x)\vert \leqslant f^{\prime\prime}(\xi) $". So it would seem that $\xi$ is simply chosen to be the maximum point of $f^{\prime\prime}$ (in absolute value) in the considered interval.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error term means that *somewhere* in the interval $(a,b)$, there is a point $\xi$ where the error exactly balances the approximation to give you an exact result. You don't know where $\xi$ is, just that it exists. This is why the trapezoid rule is exact for linear functions, because $f''(x)=0$. In fact, if you're integrating a quadratic function $f(x)=ax^2+bx+c$, you know that $f''(x)=2a$, and you can use the fact that $f''(\xi)=2a$ to also exactly determine your integral numerically.

Comment: I see, because we get a constant when differentiating, we actully don't really need to know the exact value of that point. Do you know what would happen if what we would get after double differentiation would not be a constant?

Comment: If $f''(x)$ is not a constant, then you can't use any "trick" like this to get an exact value. However, you can put a bound on your error term by looking at the global max and min of $f''(x)$ on the interval $[a,b]$.